# insert values from textarea HTML input into a column of google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm pulling values from a `textarea` tag in html and trying to insert them into a column in google sheets
in order to make a contact list to use later. The user copy pastes from an excel column a list of phone numbers into the text area input.

(the sheet gets created)

Where am I going wrong

```
<script>
function createGroup() {
  var number = document.getElementById('group').value;
  var name = document.getElementById('groupName').value;

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(groupCreated).newGroup(number, name);
 return false;
}
</script>
```

This is the code.gs script (server side)

```
function newGroup(number, name){


  var num = number;
       
      //I need to format them to +155555555 format
  var prefix = "+1";
  var removeDashes = num.replace(/-/g,"");
  var addPrefix = prefix + removeDashes;
  var format = addPrefix.replace(/\n/g," +1");
  var arr = format.split(" ");
  
  var array = arr.slice(0);

   
  var length = arr.length;
  
  var sheetName = name;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
  var newSheet = ss.insertSheet(sheetName);
  
  var activate = newSheet.activate();
  var range = activate.getRange(1, 1, length);
  range.setValues(array);
  return "Done";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

This creates the dialog with the textarea in the sidebar.

```
function sidebardialog(obj) {
  var html='<form><textarea name="text" cols="32" rows="15"></textarea><br /><input type="button" value="Paste" onclick="google.script.run.pasteHere(this.parentNode);" />';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html));
}
```

This function pastes the column of data starting at the current cell and pasting downward.  When you click on the Paste button in the sidebar

```
function pasteHere(obj) {
  const rA=obj.text.split('\n').map(function(r){return [r];});//creates a 2 d column array
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();//using the contained spreadsheet
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();//the active sheet
  const row=sh.getActiveCell().getRow();
  const col=sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  sh.getRange(row,col,rA.length,1).setValues(rA);//pastes all of the data at one time
}

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Tools')
  .addItem('Paste Data', 'sidebardialog')
  .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm working on a web app so I adapted  your method and it worked my only issue is it creates a extra cell with just the prefix "+1". I suppose it's because theres a `\n` after the last cell. Is there a way to get rid of it?

Comment: Ok took care of that with `rA.pop()` Thanks @Cooper!

Comment: You could use filter method to.

Comment: How would I do reverse, if I'm pulling the values from the Spreadsheet, now they're 2D how do I convert it into a long Array

Comment: If you're pasting them into a text area I think they're no longer a 2D array

Comment: If they are a 2D array then don't paste them into the text area use setValues() to put them into the sheet.

Comment: No I want to use them in a `for (var i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)` statement to loop a function over them

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. How about providing an example?

Comment: OK I got it, I just used `values.flat()` Thanks @Cooper for all your help